# How to sort this data inside the field based on the recent Date

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssis

I have a data in the field as " Date: `03-21-13 12/13/14/15` Date:`04-21-13 39/12/34/14` Date:`04-19-13 19/45/65/12` ".How to sort this data inside the field based on the recent Date.

It should Look like

- Date:`04-21-13 39/12/34/14`
- Date:`04-19-13 19/45/65/12`
- Date: `03-21-13 12/13/14/15`

Comment: Hello.  Can you explain in a bit more detail exactly what data you have?  Do you have a single field which contains text which contains three dates?  Do you have something else?

Comment: Please elaborate more so we can help .

Comment: Yes the data is text which contains three or more dates.But when i create a report the data in the field should be displayed as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing it as text, you cannot correctly sort directly on the column (as you appear to have discovered).  You will need to split the column, and then sort on that.  Something like:

```
Declare @tvTable Table (
    TextColumn varchar(max)
)

Insert  @tvTable
Select  '04-19-13 19/45/65/12'
Union All
Select  '04-21-13 39/12/34/14'
Union All
Select  '03-21-13 12/13/14/15'
Union All
Select  '03-25-13 17/18/19/20'
Union All
Select  '05-01-13 99/88/77/66'
Union All
Select  '02-01-13 11/22/33/44'

Select  t.TextColumn
From    @tvTable t
Cross Apply dbo.fncDelimitedSplit8k(TextColumn, ' ') split
Where   split.ItemNumber = 1
Order By Cast(split.Item As DateTime) Desc
```

The split function taken from [Jeff Moden Tally OH!](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)